# Best practice for looping through Db data and displaying in Asp.net 4.0 without Webforms!

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Assuming that the data has been retrieved from the Db and put into an object people.

```
foreach (People p in people)
{
    // create an html button for each p

     PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add("control");
}
```

Although it does not follow the MVC pattern, I would like a method that loop through the data in the controller. I have been trying to do this with dynamic controls which has turned into a major nightmare.

**EDIT:** I would like to use Webform but not for the creation of dynamic content. If for example you created a CRUD system with dynamic controls against a db, the complexity of keeping the creation, deletion in the db in sync with the actions in the page lifecycle is fairly great. For all other static content, webforms are actually pretty decent.

So, to recap, the solution I am looking for would actually exist in a webforms page, however, the loop would not create dynamic webform controls, but rather standard html controls.

Comment: Curiously - What problems are you experiencing with the dynamic controls?

Comment: I would like to use Websforms for static controls.

Comment: Performing CRUD operations on db data and having these changed reflected in an .aspx page is anything but simple when you use asp.enet server controls. (ie. create a button with ID of user to be deleted, then click button and delete a user with ID: 34 in dba nd have this change relfected in the .aspx page with the button noew removed. The page lifecycle in asp.net makes this very difficult. This is why I considered using just plain html controls.

Comment: Yes it is easy to do this in MVC.  In WebForms it is not *that* difficult though for what you described.  You just need to make sure you thoroughly understand the page lifecycle and how controls are generated during the sequence of those events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would pass the collection to the view. Then iterate through each item in the collection and add the html code there.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a MVC site (and since you mentioned not WebForms I assume it is), you ***REALLY*** want to do it in your view. It's both easy and proper to do it there. Doing it in the controller means that to output it you're going to have to override the result and return your results rather then what's in the view, which is not the way to go.

If you need to perform some kind of action on the data, then looping through it in the controller makes sense (and you already have the code to do that). But not if your goal is to create buttons. Do that in the view.

Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish? Maybe that will help some, but all I can recommend right now is to not do what you're doing and instead create the buttons with a loop in the view.

Comment: Performing CRUD operations on db data and having these changed reflected in an .aspx page is anything but simple when you use asp.enet server controls. (ie. create a button with ID of user to be deleted,  then click button and delete a user with ID: 34 in dba nd have this change relfected in the .aspx page with the button noew removed. The page lifecycle in asp.net makes this very difficult. This is why I considered using just plain html controls.

Comment: If you want to do that, then you should look at using MVC. That makes it a lot easier then dealing with WebForms does. If you really do want to do it in WebForms, you can use a repeater or worst case scenario create a StringBuilder, build HTML into it using a loop in code, and stick the result into a label.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something really special that for some reason you can't use Views for(you said not webforms and not MVC?), then I have just the project for you. I created a little project named [EView](http://github.com/Earlz/EView) for very simple rendering of HTML(or anything else) as a lightweight compile-time view. I'll admit the documentation is a bit out of date, but most of what's out of date is just features that were added. It's BSD licensed.

An example:

Templates/SomeView.html:

```
{@ Title as string; @}
<html><head>
<title>{=Title=}</title>
<body>
Hey check out the dynamic title
</body>
</html>
```

SomeCode.cs:

```
var view=new SomeView();
view.Title="Some View Title";
response.Write(view.EViewRender()); //render returns a string
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd prefer to not have either a MVC View nor traditional ASP.NET WebForm, you could create a http handler to spit out your results directly to the browser

```
 <!-- Register you're handler web.config -->
 <system.web>
 ...
     <httpHandlers>
         <add verb="*" path="People.axd" type="YourLibNameSpace, PeopleHandlerFactory" />
     </httpHandlers>
 ...
 </system.web>

 public class PeopleHandlerFactory: IHttpHandlerFactory
 {
      public virtual IHttpHandler GetHandler(HttpContext context, string requestType, string url, string pathTranslated)
    {

         Page p = new Page();
        p.SetRenderMethodDelegate(delegate (HtmlTextWriter writer) 
            {
                // ... some standard html tags if so desired
                foreach (var person in People)
                {
                    writer.Write(person.ToString());
                }
            });
         return p;
    }
 }
```

But if you're using MVC views, your controller would be setup like this

```
public class PeopleController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var people = Repository.GetPeople();
        return View(people);
    }
 ....
 }
```

Your View (Razor .cshtml) would look something like the following

```
www.site.com/people/

@model IEnumerable<People>
@foreach (var person in Model)
{
    @person.Name
}
```